# On Load Popup Window - Adobe Flash

Tags: javascript, flash, actionscript, popup

I'm trying to load an popup window on launch when I use an swf file in adobe flash, would anyone have a code that can do that either using javascript or actionscript?

Comment: what have you tried so far ? please improve your answer and provide some more information.

Comment: I have tried using javascript in a notepad file and it worked with that it opened up the new popup window fine but the same code does not work in adobe flash, i cannot post the code because it is too long

Comment: Are you trying to popup a window on HTML page or in SWF?

Answer (score 0):

The entire code is not needed to be written. You have to write the particular part of the code for the particular action on the particular Keyframe wherever u need it.
For example : If u need an alert box at a particular button Click, u write the code on that Button,

```
this.button.addEventListener("click", fl_MouseClickHandler_2.bind(this));

function fl_MouseClickHandler_2()
{
// Start your custom code
// This example code displays the words "Mouse clicked" in the Output panel.
alert("Mouse clicked");
// End your custom code
}
```

Comment: Sorry i'm new to this, i am not sure where the code i need would go so i will post al of the code in different comments ok?

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
         <head>
   <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
<!-- Begin
function popUp(URL) {
day = new Date();
id = day.getTime();
eval("page" + id + " = window.open(URL, '" + id + "', 'toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,location=0,statusbar=0,menubar=0,resizable=0,width=800,height=800,left = 560,top = 140');");
}
// End -->
</script>

Comment: <meta charset="utf-8"/>
   <title> This is my first website </title>
         </head>
         <body>
   <BODY onLoad="javascript:popUp('https://www.google.co.uk/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=M7QvVf72MsXH8ge4poGQDA&gws_rd=ssl')">
  <p> <strong>Automatic Popup!!!</strong></p>
  <hr>
  <!--check this paragraph for typo's-->
  <p> It's Aweswome!!!! </p>
         </body>
</html>

Comment: No when I load the SWF file in my browser I want it to popup on it's own